# DBPedia online mirror with SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

dbpedia.org is down about 24 hours (may be more) due a hardware problem.
Does any DBPedia online mirror exist with SPARQL endpoint? (with possibility to save  the query results)

Comment: live.dbpedia.org/sparql for instance

Comment: what means save query results?

Comment: live.dbpedia.org/sparql is also down. in browser i could - save page as results or a button on the from - save results as

Comment: dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql IS DOWN also

Comment: http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql with default graph http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: You can store any result by using curl or wget on the command line